# How to find the time for each step of the process in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, logging, pyspark, explain

I use the following function written in `PySpark` to log steps in a SQL table.

```
def log_df_update(spark,IsComplete,Status,EndDate,ErrorMessage,RowCounts,StartDate,FilePath,tablename):
        import pandas as pd
        l = [(process_name_log.value,process_id_log.value,IsComplete,Status,StartDate,EndDate,ErrorMessage,int(RowCounts),FilePath)]
        schema = (StructType([StructField("SourceName", StringType(), True),StructField("SourceID", IntegerType(), True),StructField("IsComplete", IntegerType(), True),StructField("Status", StringType(), True),StructField("StartDate", TimestampType(), True),StructField("EndDate", TimestampType(), True),StructField("ErrorMessage", StringType(), True),StructField("RowCounts", IntegerType(), True),StructField("FilePath", StringType(), True)]))
        rdd_l = sc.parallelize(l)
        log_df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd_l,schema)
        log_df.withColumn("StartDate",from_utc_timestamp(log_df.StartDate,"PST")).withColumn("EndDate",from_utc_timestamp(log_df.EndDate,"PST")).write.jdbc(url=url, table=tablename,mode="append", properties=properties)
```

The SQL table where this log is created is loaded using a JDBC connection using a separate function.

I makes logs after every step in the process irrespective of whether it failed or not to track the run time as well as completion. So before every step I store the current time in the variable `start_date`. What i dont know is if the step that is being processed or computed is taking time or if the logging of the process status is taking time. Since the start date-time is from the moment the snipped starts i cant say which is taking time.

To read data from the same table in the SQL server takes few seconds so would it take the same time to write into the table too?

I tried running `explain()` after logging but that only tells what happened till the step before the logging itself. How can i track the time taken for each step in PySpark.

Comment: Using Spark to write a single row to a database is a __serious__ overkill. You can get exact timings from Spark UI / REST endpoint, but you can expect that process you use will be slow. If you really want to log to a database (it doesn't sound like such a good idea), just use native tools.

Comment: I concur with @zero323  Spark isn't the right tool for this purpose.

Comment: @zero323 @eliasah; I dont log all the steps, just some milestones within the code. In total about 10 steps is logged. The reason for logging is to track at which step the process failed if it does and also other API's are called based on the these logs. Some are SQL stored-procs and others are just emails sent to certain people.

Comment: Still, just use native connector (for example `psycopg2` with PostgreSQL), not Spark. Using Spark `DataFrame` is just a bad idea.

Comment: @zero323 Thanks.